# How do I import react-admin in a React Typescript appplication?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I'm trying to set up a react-admin app in typescript and I can't quite figure out how to import react-admin. It gives me the (simple) error saying

```
"Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-admin'. 
'.../node_modules/react-admin/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/react-admin` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
 file containing `declare module 'react-admin';`"
```

@types/react-admin is not a valid package but I couldn't find anyone else complaining about this on github or stackoverflow. Am I missing something? As far as I can see, most things have already been migrated to typescript.

Edit: Found [this](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3242) which actually references the problem with ts. However it's been 5 months since they said "it will take months"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Current version of react-admin does not export types definition. To make your project to compile you need to create `index.d.ts` file and modify `tsconfig.json`.

```
├── @types
│   └── react-admin
│       └── index.d.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["./@types"],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

```
// index.d.ts
declare module 'react-admin';
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer. As a general rule, declaring the module in index.d.ts will generally work.

Answer (score 0):

if the issue exist after after the .d.ts file creation, use `"noImplicitAny": false,` in your tsconfig.json