# Implement Typescript with React admin

Tags: react-admin

I did: `create-react-app with --typescript` flag

Then install react admin version 3.0

and I got this in console:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-admin'. 
'.../node_modules/react-admin/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/react-admin` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
 file containing `declare module 'react-admin';`
```

Any advice please or a guide please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import react-admin in a React Typescript appplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838216/how-do-i-import-react-admin-in-a-react-typescript-appplication)